# ASP.NET how to change background color of table row on button click + row entry?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a table with one row which is filled in with values after the user clicks a button. I want to change the background color of the row to different colors based on the values that are filled in to the row.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Search" />
<tr>
    <td runat="server" id ="td1" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td2" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td3" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td4" class="auto-style1"></td>
</tr>
```

and my Button1_Click function looks like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[]toDisp = someFunction();
    td1.InnerText = toDisp[0];
    td2.InnerText = toDisp[1];
    td3.InnerText = toDisp[2];
    td4.InnerText = toDisp[3];
}
```

Basically, I want  to set the background color of the table row based on the value of toDisp[1]. How should I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its going to be just 1 row

just set a ID to it with runat attribute

```
<tr id="test" runat="server">
    <td runat="server" id ="td1" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td2" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td3" class="auto-style1"></td>
    <td runat="server" id ="td4" class="auto-style1"></td>
</tr>
```

then based on the condition of toDisp[1]

you can write a switch statement or Random (based on color requirement) to just set

```
test.BgColor = "SomeColor";
```

Comment: is there a constants to represent colors?